# nodejs windows modules directory

Tags: node.js

I am new at nodejs. This is my first install. I have installed node js on windows 8 and I want to install modules with command

`npm install yuicompressor`

**C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules**

But my nodejs is installed to **C:\Program Files\nodejs** directory and there is a folder named **node_modules** in here.

My npm module installation is going to **C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules**

is this an issue.

Comment: If you're installing the way you claim you are above it is going to whatever directory you're in (it's a local module) - if you're installing with the `-g` flag that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

> There are two ways to install npm packages: locally or globally. You
>   choose which kind of installation to use based on how you want to use
>   the package.
>
> If you want to depend on the package from your own module using
>   something like Node's require, then you want to install locally. On
>   the other hand, if you want to use it as a command line tool,
>   something like the grunt CLI, then you want to install it globally.

— https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally

> To download packages globally, you simply use the command `npm install -g <package>`

— https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally

Comment: global packages are going to C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm, but nodejs installation is in C:\Program Files\nodejs, I wonder this.